# laravel 7 blade component public methods not working

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I have a problem with my Laravel project in using [blade component](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#components).

When I define a new component and want to use "Component public Methods" to pass data to "view component blade file", I receive an error, "Undefined variable"

The component has been made by

```
php artisan make:component testc
```

and i try

```
cache:clear

view:clear
```

and `composer dump` before

and has following codes:

**component code**

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class testc extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.testc');
    }

    public function test()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

**view component blade file**

```
<div>
    {{ $test }}
</div>
```

**and my error**

[image]

ps: laravel version is : 7.18.0

Comment: From that [page you linked](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#passing-data-to-components): "_You should define the component's required data in its class constructor. All public properties on a component will automatically be made available to the component's view._" Your component class doesn't have any public properties

Comment: @kerbh0lz not exactly
when you should pass data to your component you need to define variable in constructor method
but when you pass data to blade any public methods or variable can be accessible on component's balde

Comment: I am wondering that this even works, don't you get an `include(...app/View/Components/Testc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` error because your component is `testc` and not `Testc`?

Comment: @kerbh0lz hey bro have any idea to fix it , i have problem again 
look at https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/33454

Comment: Please post a new question for a new problem

Answer (score 3):

- In your blade file you should call the method of your component like this:

```
<div>
   {{ $test() }}
</div>
```

- Notice the brackets.